# Python - TypeError: __init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, class

I've seen this question before, but I couldn't resolve the issue...

I've only started to learn to program for the past 4 days, so it's probably something very basic. Here is my code from two diff files:

```
from Children import children_eating

keely_kids = [
    "Ella",
    "Jonathan",
    "Nathanael",
    "Daniel"
]

what_kids_chewing = [
    children_eating(keely_kids, [0], True),
    children_eating(keely_kids, [1], True)
]

#print(what_kids_chewing)
```

---

```
class children_eating:
    def __init__(self, name, is_chewing):
    self.name = name
    self.is_chewing = is_chewing
```

Comment: You're passing too many parameters to your function. `self` is implicit, it's not a parameter you pass explicitly. I think what you want is `children_eating(keely_kids[0], True)`.

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `__init__` you do not have to pass `self`. It is done automatically.
The `keely_kids, [0],` is also not a correct way to use a table. You should use `keely_kids[0]`.
In summary, use:

```
what_kids_chewing = [
    children_eating(keely_kids[0], True),
    children_eating(keely_kids[1], True)
]
```

Comment: We call that a *list* in Python.

Answer (score 1):

`def __init__(self, name, is_chewing)` means , you can only pass 2 arguments(`name` and `is_chewing`) to the class's initializer. First parameter which is `self` is automatically filled by a reference to the newly created object by Python. So it is reserved.

But in `children_eating(keely_kids, [0], True)` you passed 3 three arguments, also Python itself filled the first one(passes one). This is why you get that error.

Answer (score 1):

when passing a list using indexes it's like this children_eating(keely_kids[0], True),. Just overwrite the line and your code will work.

`what_kids_chewing = [ children_eating(keely_kids[0], True), children_eating(keely_kids[1], True) ]`

Answer (score 0):

The class `children_eating` has a constructor (the `__init__` method) accepting only two elements, as explained below:

```
class children_eating:
    def __init__(self, name, is_chewing):  
        # the inputs to this method are: "name" and "is_chewing"
        self.name = name
        self.is_chewing = is_chewing
```

In fact, the `self` refers to the class internal state, and it is automatically passed to the method by python itself. When you call the method, you can simply ignore the `self`. Just pass values for `name` and `is_chewing`.
On the contrary, when you write:

```
children_eating(keely_kids, [0], True)
```

in both cases, you are giving too many inputs, getting the error:

> __ init __() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

which tells you that you are actually giving the method 4 parameters instead of 3. In fact, the method receives `keely_kids`, `[0]`, and `True`, plus the `self` (which is automatically given internally).

You can correctly call the class constructor as:

```
children_eating(keely_kids[0], True)
```